# Array(push - object) not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with pushing object into an array.
I set an object with values and push them to the array. I then change some of the values of the object and push the object into the array again.
However, on inspection, both objects pushed into the array are identical, both object's values are identical to the last object that was pushed into the array.

```
let ProductPosition = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

let PalletType = (function () {
    function PalletType() {
        this.PatternType = '';
        this.ProductWidth = 0;
        this.PalletWidth = 0;
        this.ProductPositions = [];
    }
});

function getPalletPositions(pallet, pattern) {
    pal.ProductPositions = [];
    let posn = new ProductPosition();
    switch (pattern) {
        case '1U1':
            posn = [];
            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2;
            posn.angle = 0;
            posn.apprDir = 0;
            pallet.ProductPositions.push(posn);
            break;
        case '2U1':
            posn = [];
            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2 + pal.ProductWidth / 2;
            console.log('y pos 0 ' + posn.y);
            pal.ProductPositions.push(posn);//first push

            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2 - pal.ProductWidth / 2;
            console.log('y pos 1 ' + posn.y);
            pallet.ProductPositions.push(posn);//first push
            break;
    }
}
let pal = new PalletType();

pal.PalletWidth = 1165;
pal.ProductWidth = 400
let pat = '2U1';

getPalletPositions(pal, pat);

pal.ProductPositions.forEach(function (pos) {
    console.log("pos.y:" + pos.y);
});
```

Actual output:

```
y pos 0 782.5 <-value of y of first push
y pos 1 382.5 <-value of y of second push
pos.y:382.5   <-should be 782.5
pos.y:382.5
```

I'd expect:

```
y pos 0 782.5 <-value of y of first push
y pos 1 382.5 <-value of y of second push
pos.y:782.5
pos.y:382.5
```

I'm totally baffled and tried a few things, but to no avail.

Comment: because you are changing the same object... you need to make a deep clone and make the changes

Comment: You can Use the (https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) method or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`

Comment: What is `let PalletType = (function () {
    function PalletType() {
        this.PatternType = '';
        this.ProductWidth = 0;
        this.PalletWidth = 0;
        this.ProductPositions = [];
    }
});` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You were mutating that object you can use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator or [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Check below

```
let ProductPosition = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

let PalletType = (function () {
    function PalletType() {
        this.PatternType = '';
        this.ProductWidth = 0;
        this.PalletWidth = 0;
        this.ProductPositions = [];
    }
});

function getPalletPositions(pallet, pattern) {
    pal.ProductPositions = [];
    let posn = new ProductPosition();
    debugger;
    switch (pattern) {
        case '1U1':
            posn = [];
            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2;
            posn.angle = 0;
            posn.apprDir = 0;
            pallet.ProductPositions.push(posn);
            break;
        case '2U1':
            posn = [];
            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2 + pal.ProductWidth / 2;
            console.log('y pos 0 ' + posn.y);
            pal.ProductPositions.push({...posn});//first push

            posn.y = pal.PalletWidth / 2 - pal.ProductWidth / 2;
            console.log('y pos 1 ' + posn.y);
            pallet.ProductPositions.push({...posn});//first push
            break;
    }
}
let pal = new PalletType();

pal.PalletWidth = 1165;
pal.ProductWidth = 400
let pat = '2U1';

getPalletPositions(pal, pat);

pal.ProductPositions.forEach(function (pos) {
    console.log("pos.y:" + pos.y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because "posn" is an Object, so you are actually pushing a reference to this object rather than a primitive value.
You could, for example, copy the object:

```
pallet.ProductPositions.push({...posn});
```

The Spread operator will create a shallow copy.
If you need a deep copy use the following:

```
pallet.ProductPositions.push(JSON.Parse(JSON.Stringify(posn)));
```

Pay attention that the JSON method is not able to copy functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to push the same object 2 times in the same array. The first time with some value and next time, you're modifying the value in the same object and pushing in the array. So in total the same object reference is getting modified. As a result, the array has same object added 2 times.

Another way is, you can use slice operator on your array to create new instance of the array and then do the second push. OR create 2 different variables and then push it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your prompt responses, it is very much appreciated.

Solved by using:

```
let x;
let y;
let angle;
let apprDir;
```

and assigning these directly. Then:

```
pallet.ProductPositions.push(new ProductPosition(x, y, angle, apprDir));
```

Works a treat and simplified the code.